# What if Eureka server is down

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I want to know, how to handle retry count from eureka client to eureka server is eureka server goes down? i.e how to stop eureka client from sending heartbeat to eureka server when eureka server is down.

Comment: Why should it stop sending the heartbeat? Whats the problem with just continue sending heartbeats until the server is back again?

Comment: @YannicKlem so that the client does not fill up the logs in every 30 seconds. My eureka client is a deployable war, I dont want the logs to be filled up in every 30 seconds.

Comment: So your real question is how to prevent the eureka client from logging this error?

Comment: You can say that too. I have tried a lot of things but nothing has worked so far. I want eureka client to log this error at least a few times before it stops trying to connect to eureka server.

Comment: @Divyanshi, were you able to figure out a solution for this. i am also looking forward for the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for solutions using the Netflix OSS suite, use [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) . Or you could add a custom circuit breaker, based on retry.

Comment: I am new to Netflix OSS, isn't hystrix used to break a connection between eureka server and client if client doesn't send heartbeat ?
Here, client is sending the heartbeat but since eureka is not reachable it can't be processed further.
Can you provide me with any substantial link where circuit breaker is implemented at client side?

Comment: Hystrix is a just a wrapper around network calls it can work either way. it doesn't distinguish, infact Eureka doesn't know about Hystrix per-se. If you need totorials on Hystrix, check, 
http://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-hystrix,   https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-examples

Comment: You just need to wrap your call to eureka Server with Hystrix, so that it breaks  circuit when the Server is down, preventing unnecessary calls.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the eureka client continue to send heartbeat so that the whole system would be resume after the eureka server is back.

If eureka client stops to send heartbeat, how does it know the server is resumed or not?

Comment: In such cases i would like to reduce the frequency of calls to Eureka server and also suppress the errors. Any solution for this?

Comment: @Ankit I was able to suppress the errors by handling them in the application server settings and creating a separate log for the errors. I also created a backup eureka server in case the first one is down.